# How to handle or minimize tight coupling in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, coding-style, decoupling

### Description

By design most jquery code leads to a lot of tight coupling, e.g. selectors assume a specific structure of html

```
var mySubnav = $("#navigation a.sub-menu");
```

If the corresponding html changes, for whatever reasons,

```
<a class="subMenu" .... </a>
```

functionality is broken.

### Question

- What's the best way to handle tight coupling?
- What approaches exist to loosen it up?

### Answers, Approaches

- use the html custom data attribute to separate css from js logic. e.g. add `data-submenu="true"` on the html and use `var mySubnav = $("[data-submenu]");` on the js side.
- implement a solid testing environment
- couple as loose as possible, by using the least specific selectors, e.g. `$("a.sub-menu')`. [See also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682748/best-practice-for-css-class-naming-for-use-with-jquery-selectors)
- Eliminate the actual string literals that represent CSS selectors from the body of your jQuery code by (1) retrieving references to static DOM elements beforehand, and (2) storing selector strings in one place (at the top of your code).
- use javascript frameworks, like *Backbone*, which decouple javascript from the DOM via *views*
- use [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) and [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) regarding coupling due to event management

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682748/best-practice-for-css-class-naming-for-use-with-jquery-selectors

Comment: Related: http://jondavidjohn.com/blog/2012/04/decoupling-style-from-functionality-javascript-and-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Use Custom prefixed classes for UI hooks `ui-specificGuy`

**Provided HTML**

```
<div class="container grid8">
    <ul class="ul1 horizontal">
        <li>List Item 1</li>
        <li>List Item 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Bad** - using style purposed classes/hooks

```
$('.container.grid8').stuff();
$('.ul1.horizontal').moreStuff();
```

**Adjusting the HTML**

```
<div class="container grid8 ui-specificContainer">
    <ul class="ul1 horizontal ui-specificList">
        <li>List Item 1</li>
        <li>List Item 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Good** - using your own purposed classes/hooks

```
$('.ui-specificContainer').stuff();
$('.ui-specificList').moreStuff();
```

## Only be as specific as neccessary

If this will accomplish your goal.

```
$('.ui-targetedElement')
```

Then why have a selector that looks like this?

```
$('ul > li a.ui-targetedElement')
```

This simply introduces unnecessary DOM structure dependencies into the functionality you are building, and you should be able to be proactive in this regard because you should be providing your own hooks (prefixed classes) at this point right?

**Ultimately though I would say that tight coupling between the DOM and the script are sometimes unavoidable because of the nature of how they work together.**

**[Full Article](http://jondavidjohn.com/blog/2012/04/decoupling-style-from-functionality-javascript-and-jquery)**

Comment: What if there are more than 1 `a.sub-menu` and he wants to get to the one inside `#navigation`?

Comment: We're speaking of hypotheticals here, I go on to make the point I am trying to illustrate... **being as least specific as you can to achieve the desired result**

Comment: we can have a 15 comment conversation about a HTML document that doesn't exist if you wan't, but don't miss the point I'm trying to make.

Comment: It's not hypothetical if you use specifics. For the sake of argument, you can further generalize it just `.sub-menu`. That way, if the HTML changes from `a` to `input`, it would still select 'something' but does that sound right to you? Point is, changing your source code changes everything. There is a difference between coupling and relation.

Comment: You're still arguing with me about the structure of an HTML document that doesn't exist. sure, you can throw out "what-ifs" until you're blue in the face but define exactly what you disagree with.  Do you think you should be as absolutely specific as possible?

Comment: I'm saying your simplification is not correct (at least not without the disclaimer that there is only one such anchor tag on the page).

Comment: I don't know, if it adds anything to the discussion, but in my original case, $("a.sub-menu') wouldn't have done the trick. Nevertheless I support the idea to be as least specific as possible. So I would call it a draw ;) Many Thanks!

Comment: Good grief, you're still going on and on about the specific DOM structure of a non-existent file, you're missing the forest for the trees.

Answer (score 6):

This may not be a popular answer, but... testing, testing, testing.  JQuery and Javascript in general are typically tightly coupled, and for good reason; they're code running in the browser, and so you want to keep the performance relatively snappy.  So injecting an indirection layer that allows for looser coupling can decrease performance; as well, it can be a bit of overkill, since there's typically a close pairing between the JQuery / Javascript code that's written and the pages they're written for; this is as much an artifact of the historical development of Javascript, but that's the way that it is.  As such, the tight coupling is pretty "normal".

The way to deal with this tight coupling, like any tight coupling, is to make sure that you've got good testing in place to cover any coupling failures.  Testing can provide assurance that the coupling is proper, and it's really the best way to assure the functionality you expect anyway.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use a Javascript framework, like [Backbone](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/). It gives you the concept of views which help decouple your Javascript from the DOM structure. For example, you can create the Comment view, which you assign to the following div:

```
<div class="comment">
    <span class="title"></span>
    <p class="body"></p>
</div>
```

And then you can access elements in the view relative to the `comment` div:

```
var title = this.$(".title");
```

This makes it easy to change the DOM structure outside of the `comment` div as long as the internals of the `comment` div remain the same.

Comment: or knockout.js ... in my experience, it's far quicker to set up a tightly coupled app as it's "just got to do this one thing", which rapidly turns into a whole bunch of other things, so you have to do a big rewrite to the decoupled version, which involves a nightmare refactoring and abstraction. So you might as well do it properly from the beginning ...   in my experience ...

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking in respect to event management then make as much use of delegates and live which are not tightly coupled to the dom structure. Take a look at the below urls

Live - 
http://api.jquery.com/live/

Delegate - 
http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to:

1. retrieve the references of static DOM elements on DOM ready and put them in variables or properties of an object or whatever.
2. store class names inside an object (or several objects or whatever, as long as those names (strings) are in one place)

Then you can do this:

```
var mySubnav = $('a.' + C.submenu, navigation);
```

where `navigation` is a reference to the `#navigation` element and `C` is the class-names object which `submenu` property is the string `"sub-menu"`.

Now, when you change class-names in your HTML code, you only have to update the `C` object.

The idea is to **get rid of the actual string literals that represent CSS selectors from the body of your jQuery code** by (1) retrieving references to static DOM elements beforehand, and (2) storing selector strings in one place (at the top of your code).

Answer (score 1):

If your html changes, the all bets are off.

And what you have is not tight coupling. It is essential for your code to function.

E.g., this is what I would consider tight coupling:

```
<a class="subMenu" onclick="doSomething()"> .... </a>
```

The loose version would be:

```
$("#navigation a.sub-menu').click(function(){
   //do something
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using html5 data attributes to do javascript selectors?

```
<a data-submenu="true" .... </a>

var mySubnav = $("[data-submenu]");
```

Makes it really clear that javascript is operating on the html.

Comment: This sacrifices speed of DOM selection by about double ... http://jsperf.com/jquery-selector-data-attr-vs-class/5 ... see my answer for a solution to does not make this sacrifice... http://stackoverflow.com/a/6820621/555384

Comment: If dom selection is a bottleneck, then yeah, I would use classes.